# Serial Ports in a .DLL file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, serial-port

I have created `.dll` file in Visual C++.
It includes a function which takes two arguments and send data through serial port. Next i wanted to include this `.dll` in my application and call these functions. But i am unable to call these functions. Kindly Help.

Here is header file for my `.dll`

```
 namespace positioncontrol

{  
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;

  public ref class control

    {   
    static int rotate(char a, String^ b);

    };
}
```

And here is `.cpp` for my `.dll`

```
   #include "goniometer.h"    

    namespace positioncontrol
    { 

   void control::rotate(char a, String^ b)
    {        SerialPort^ serialPort = gcnew SerialPort(L"COM5",9600,Parity::None,1,StopBits::One);          
             int inp_rotation;
             array<unsigned char>^ inp_c = gcnew array<unsigned char>(2);   
             String^ inp_string;                                             
             inp_c[0] = a;
             inp_string= b;                                     
             inp_rotation=Int32::Parse(inp_string);                         
             inp_c[1] = (unsigned char)inp_rotation;
             serialPort->Write(inp_c,0,2);                                         
        }
     }
```

I am using this .dll in a desktop application. I have include the header file

```
#ifndef goniometer_h
#define goniometer_h
#include "goniometer.h"
#endif
```

Added the path for include directories and added .dll as a reference.
Now i am using the function defined in .dll for a click event

```
private: System::Void button9_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

              char dir;       
              dir = 0x42;
              String^ inp_string;                                                
              inp_string=enter_degree->Text; 
              positioncontrol::control::rotate(dir,inp_string);                                                      

         }
```

Now when i build my desktop application i am getting following error

```
1>C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Final\Motor_Dual_API\Debug\goniometer.h(10): error C2011: 'positioncontrol::control' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\dell\desktop\final\vc++dll\debug\goniometer.dll : see declaration of 'positioncontrol::control'
1>c:\users\dell\desktop\final\motor_dual_api\motor_next\Form1.h(530): error C2027: use of undefined type 'positioncontrol::control'
1>          c:\users\dell\desktop\final\vc++dll\debug\goniometer.dll : see declaration of 'positioncontrol::control'
1>c:\users\dell\desktop\final\motor_dual_api\motor_next\Form1.h(530): error C3861: 'rotate': identifier not found
1>c:\users\dell\desktop\final\motor_dual_api\motor_next\Form1.h(540): error C2027: use of undefined type 'positioncontrol::control'
1>          c:\users\dell\desktop\final\vc++dll\debug\goniometer.dll : see declaration of 'positioncontrol::control'
1>c:\users\dell\desktop\final\motor_dual_api\motor_next\Form1.h(540): error C3861: 'rotate': identifier not found
```

Kindly help me in figuring out error.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: I don't see a declaration for the "serialPort" variable in your snippet.  Nor does the compiler so it complains about it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the namespace separator is `::` rather than `.`. Check your `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not define `serialPort`. Add the definition to the global namespace, to the namespace `positionControl` or as an auto variable in your function

From the semantic point of view, `serialPort` is a pointer. So must also create an instance of the object, where serialPort points to.